# how can I change error view of laravel 5.2 like 5.3?

Tags: laravel, syntax-error

how can I change the error view of laravel 5.2 like 5.3?

I want the same error view of 5.3 in laravel 5.2... can anyone please help me in this?

From
[image]

TO

[image]

Comment: You can read the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

Comment: no information has been provided for this in Documentation

Comment: now from screenshots, I understand what you want. You need to install `filp/whoops` package.  [https://github.com/filp/whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `filp/whoops` library for that.

https://packagist.org/packages/filp/whoops

```
composer require filp/whoops
```